# error in run hadoop start-all.sh

Tags: hadoop, archlinux

i want to run hadoop in my arch linux but i have this error, how i can fix it?

```
[]# . /usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on [OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
2013-12-10 23:21:42,602 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable]
Error: Please specify one of --hosts or --hostnames options and not both.
cat: /etc/hadoop/slaves: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
2013-12-10 23:21:44,192 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
0.0.0.0]
Error: Please specify one of --hosts or --hostnames options and not both.
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/yarn-vahid-resourcemanager-kharazi.out
2013-12-10 23:21:47,901 INFO  [main] resourcemanager.ResourceManager (StringUtils.java:startupShutdownMessage(601)) - STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting ResourceManager
STARTUP_MSG:   host = kharazi/192.168.1.3
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.2.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /etc/hadoop:/etc/hadoop:/etc/hadoop:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-site-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-site-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/etc/hadoop/rm-config/log4j.properties
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1529768; compiled by 'hortonmu' on 2013-10-07T06:28Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_45
************************************************************/
cat: /etc/hadoop/slaves: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cat: /etc/hadoop/slaves: No such file or directory

You need to fill in the `/etc/hadoop/slaves` file with the location of all your slave nodes. You put one slave node hostname per line. Example:

```
host1
host2
host3
```

Make sure you can [ssh into these nodes without a password](https://www.google.com/#q=passwordless+ssh).